# Setting mouse cursor in blender bpy

Tags: python, interface, mouse

I have written the following code to programmatically set the mouse to specific locations. It works fine in the blender console but when I run in as code nothing happens, no errors are thrown. I have researched loads but cannot find a solution to this. Has anyone got any ideas ?

````
def gen_C_dict(context, window, area_type='VIEW_3D'):
    C_dict = {}
    for area in window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == area_type:
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    break
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == area_type:
                    region_data = None
                    if area_type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        region_data = space.region_3d
                    break
            break
    C_dict.update(
        window=window,
        area=area,
        region=region,
        region_data=region_data,
        screen=window.screen,
        space_data=space)
    return C_dict

context = bpy.context
targetwindow = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[1]
C_dict = gen_C_dict(context, targetwindow, area_type='VIEW_3D')
targetwindow.cursor_warp(500,200)

def SetMouseCursor(data):
    context = bpy.context
    targetwindow = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[1]
    C_dict = gen_C_dict(context, targetwindow, area_type='VIEW_3D')
    targetwindow.cursor_warp(int(data['x']),int(data['y']))


mouseLocation = {}
mouseLocation['x'] = 500
mouseLocation['y'] = 500

```
````